# Sort vector of class objects based on some member variable

Tags: class, sorting, vector

Let

```
class Record {

    public:
       Record();

    private:
       string id;
       double score;
};
```

Somewhere we define a vector of Record objects, i.e.,

```
vector<Record> records(N);
// Initialize records somehow
```

I would like to sort records based on `score` (in descending order) keeping track of the other member variables of `Record` (in this case just the `score`, but in general whatever else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the comparison operators.

```
bool Record::operator<(const Record& rhs) {
  return score < rhs.score;
}

bool Record::operator<=(const Record& rhs) {
  return score <= rhs.score;
}
```

Note, if you define `<` and `<=`, you should also probably define the other comparison operators `>`, `>=`, `==`, and `!=`.  You should also enforce a strict weak ordering (e.g. `a < b`, `b < c` implies `a < c`).

Then to sort descending, you could use the following...

```
std::sort(records.begin(), records.end(), 
  [] (const Record& lhs, const Record& rhs) -> bool { return lhs > rhs; });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Jason! Well, and how can I apply one of those operators in order to sort `records` in descending order? I think that I should call `std::sort`, as in `std::sort(records.begin(), records.end(), XXX)`. What should `XXX` be? Thanks again!

Comment: @nullgeppetto All you need is `std::sort(records.begin(), records.end())` since `Record` is comparable.

Comment: Nice, but do I need to implement all the comparison operators if I only need to sort in descending order?

Comment: Oops, you'd need to add a lambda to sort descending (e.g. `[] (const Record& lhs, const Record& rhs) -> bool { return lhs > rhs; }`).

Answer (score 1):

### To sort a vector of objects

You could **overload a comparison operator >**<sup>1</sup> for your class, which will look something like:

```
bool operator> (const Record& r1, const Record& r2) {
    return r1.score > r2.score;
}
```

or as a member function:

```
bool Record::operator> (const Record& r) {
     return score > r.score;
}
```

which will be implicitly substituted as a third parameter in:

```
std::sort(records.begin(), records.end(), overloaded_comparison_operator)
```

You could also use a **lambda function** directly in `sort`:

```
std::sort(records.begin(), records.end(), [](const Record & r1,const Record & r2) -> bool {
                                          return r1.score > r2.score; });
```

---

<sup>1. You could use any of the [comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) you find useful in your case. Bear in mind `operator <` will sort in ascending, while `operator >` in descending order.</sup>